# Не могу организовать AsyncTasc

Tags: android, java, android-asynctask, многопоточность

Как с помощью AnsysTask этот процесс выполнить перед onCreate() и передать полученные ему полученные данные!

```
try
        {

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsontwitter);
        byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
        String jsontext = new String(buffer);
        final JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);
        JSONObject post;
        try {
        post = entries.getJSONObject(0);
        detoks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        detoks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        detoks_op = post.getString("description");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(1);
        antioks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        antioks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(2);
        paks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        paks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(3);
        nutrimaks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        nutrimaks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(4);
        sveltform_k = post.getString("good_code");
        sveltform_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        post = entries.getJSONObject(5);
        chromvital_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        chromvital_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(6);
        seiftusi_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        seiftusi_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(7);
        senior_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        senior_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(8);
        lsbalans_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        lsbalans_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(11);
        senior_ledi_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        senior_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(16);
        endjoyNT_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        endjoyNT_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(17);
        osteosanum_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        osteosanum_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(19);
        direset_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        direset_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(21);
        vineks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        vineks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(22);
        breinofleks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        breinofleks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(23);
        sheviton_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        sheviton_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(24);
        neichetan_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        neichetan_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(26);
        mega_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        mega_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(27);
        bisk_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        bisk_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(28);
        revien_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        revien_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(29);
        giper_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        giper_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(30);
        mistik_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        mistik_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(31);
        passilat_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        passilat_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(32);
        ursul_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        ursul_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(33);
        lamin_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        lamin_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(34);
        artum_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        artum_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(35);
        biuty_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        biuty_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(36);
        nortia_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        nortia_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(37);
        granatin_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        granatin_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(38);
        stalon_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        stalon_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(39);
        mediossoia_k = post.getString("good_code");
        mediossoia_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    }
    catch (Exception je)
    {

    }
```

Comment: onPreExecute выполняется перед стартом задачи, onPostExecute - после и оба в UI-потоке. А расчёты нужно выполнять в doInBackground

Comment: Вставляю их туда но там не отрабатывает парсинг json. Я правильно понимаю что onPreExecute() работает одновременно с doInBackground()?
Например в doInBackground() я провожу сортировку массива но не могу использовать этом массив для вывода в onPreExecute().

Comment: Нет, не правильно. Вам надо асинком возвращать результат.

Comment: Как! Можно на этом коде показать! НЕ доезжаю я! И почему в эмуляторе работает?

Comment: Зачем столько кода кинул то? Думаешь это читабельно?        
Убери все ненужное!!!       
И перед тем как что-то прогать самому сюда зайди:      
http://startandroid.ru/ru/

Comment: Ок!
Сейчас!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо передать все нужные параметры в таску, в секции обработки обработать, в секции пост - применить/сохранить результат.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Тип входных параметров, тип прогресса, тип результата> {

    protected тип результата doInBackground(Тип входных параметров... params) {
                Делаем то что вам надо без доступа к UI.
        return И возвращаем результат;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(тип результата result) {
        тут делаем то что вам надо с результатом с возможностью доступа к UI
    }
}

new MyTask().execute(Ваши входные параметры)
```

В параметры вынесете все параметры которые получаете от UI.

Comment: на скорую руку :
    
      class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Sorted[]> {
    
        @Override
        protected Sorted[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Sorted[] sortirovka = null;
    
         /* все Ваши расчёты*/
            return sortirovka;
    
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Sorted[] sortirovka) {
          super.onPostExecute(sortirovka);
          if (sortirovka == null)
           /*I'm sorry*/
           return;
    
         txt1.setText(sortirovka[36].name);
         /* ... и т.д.*/
        }
      }

Comment: Спасибо! Но работает только в эмуляторе!

Comment: Осталось только выложить весь проект и поделиться зарплатой ))). Вставляйте логи смотрите, где не проходит, исправляйте.

Comment: Я откоректировал активность так, что она не зависит от других! Что еще необходимо? price?

Comment: InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsontwitter);

Это вынесли в параметры?

Comment: Добавил прослеживание статуса. Пишет RUNNING секунды три висит и вылетает приложение! Как заставить андроид дождаться окончания подсчетов?

Comment: Не плодите вопросы - делайте отладку.     
Если вылетает - значит в логе должен быть Exception - он Вам и скажет куда копать

Comment: Всем плюсы! И мои вопросы конечно становятся дебильными, но нет никаких ошибок в отладке на эмуляторе! Ошибка одна при его запуске на девайсе: Приложение "название приложения" остановлено!

Comment: Эмуль не эталон, как говорят сами разработчики Андрюхи, его работа может отличаться (особенно если версии API разные).    
А Вы, кажется мне, LogCat'ом не умеете пользоваться

Comment: Напишите что говорит LogCat с девайса